# Is 10.04 LTS Still Supported by the Ubuntu Desktop Advanced?

Tags: release-management

Is  10. 04 LTS Still Supported by the Ubuntu Desktop Advanced?

If yes, until when?

Comment: Yes ,untill the next april

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can check out the details [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).

[image: Support windows]