# 10.04 still receiving updates

Tags: release-management

I was under the impression that I was running 10.04 desktop on my laptop, but I am still receiving updates, latest 30 mins ago.

Is there a method to determine which distribution was initially installed, Server or Desktop ?

I have read this post, [Is 10.04 LTS Still Supported by the Ubuntu Desktop Advanced?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135507/is-10-04-lts-still-supported-by-the-ubuntu-desktop-advanced)

Comment: I don't think that 10.04 is supported any longer and Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12562/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-desktop-or-server-is-installed

Comment: I have checked both links, (and run all the checks) I am running desktop version, only explanation which makes sense is @Florian Diesch 's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period for support doesn't depend on what was initially installed but solely on the package.

A package that is considered to be a "server package" gets LTS on any installation. Packages that are considered both "server packages" and "desktop packages" get LTS as well. Packages that are considered "desktop-only" don't get LTS on any installation.

So during the server LTS period on a desktop installation you still get updates for *some* packages, but not for others.

For example it's still Firefox 20 in Ubuntu 10.04 with all its known security bugs.

Please upgrade to a still supported version of Ubuntu as soon as possible.